# Apparmor seems to break Samba after every reboot

Tags: debian, samba, apparmor

I am running a Pi with a lot of services and recognised that my `smbd.service` (Version 4.13.13-Debian) was down with the errormessage:

```
Aug 23 18:33:43 RPi64 systemd[879]: smbd.service: Failed to execute /usr/share/samba/update-apparmor-samba-profile: Exec format error
Aug 23 18:33:43 RPi64 systemd[879]: smbd.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /usr/share/samba/update-apparmor-samba-profile: Exec format error
Aug 23 18:33:43 RPi64 systemd[1]: smbd.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Aug 23 18:33:43 RPi64 systemd[1]: smbd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 23 18:33:43 RPi64 systemd[1]: Failed to start Samba SMB Daemon.
```

At first I thought my `/etc/samba/smb.conf` is wrong, but after some investigation this did not hold up. I did `apt reinstall samba` and after this the service ran fine with the old config.

But after a reboot it was broken again.

So I disabled `apparmor.service` and this finally worked.

However, I don't know if `apparmor` should be enabled in `systemd` or where it even came from. It never popped up until now. It has a line in the `systemd` file:

```
ExecStartPre=/usr/share/samba/update-apparmor-samba-profile
```

Not sure if this is usually the case. What I recently did was upgrade to `Raspbian Bullseye 64bit` and install `pivpn` with `wireguard`. Not sure this had something to do with it.

---

EDIT: After a day I could not reproduce the issue. The file looks like this:

```
pi@RPi64:~ $ sudo cat /usr/share/samba/update-apparmor-samba-profile 
#!/bin/bash

# update apparmor profile sniplet based on samba configuration
#
# This script creates and updates a profile sniplet with permissions for all
# samba shares, except
# - paths with variables (anything containing a % sign)
# - "/" - if someone is insane enough to share his complete filesystem, he'll have
#   to modify the apparmor profile himself

# (c) Christian Boltz 2011-2019
# This script is licensed under the GPL v2 or, at your choice, any later version.


# exit silently - used if no profile update is needed
silentexit() {
    # echo "$@"
    exit 0
}

# exit with an error message
verboseexit() {
    echo "$@" >&2
    exit 1
}

# if you change this script, _always_ update the version to force an update of the profile sniplet
versionstring="${0##*/} 1.2+deb"

aastatus="/usr/sbin/aa-status"
aaparser="/sbin/apparmor_parser"
loadedprofiles="/sys/kernel/security/apparmor/profiles"

smbconf="/etc/samba/smb.conf"
smbd_profile="/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.smbd"
profilesniplet="/etc/apparmor.d/samba/smbd-shares"
tmp_profilesniplet="/etc/apparmor.d/samba/smbd-shares.new"

# test -x "$aastatus" || silentexit "apparmor not installed"
# "$aastatus" --enabled || silentexit "apparmor not loaded (or not running as root)"
test -e "$loadedprofiles" || silentexit "apparmor not loaded"
test -d "/etc/apparmor.d/samba" || silentexit "directory for samba profile snippet doesn't exist"
test -r "$loadedprofiles" || verboseexit "no read permissions for $loadedprofiles - not running as root?"

widelinks=$(testparm -s --parameter-name "wide links" 2>/dev/null)
test "$widelinks" == "Yes" && {
    echo "[$(date '+%Y/%m/%d %T')] $(basename $0)"
    echo '  WARNING: "wide links" enabled. You might need to modify the smbd apparmor profile manually.'
} >> /var/log/samba/log.smbd

grep -q "$versionstring" "$profilesniplet" && {
    test "$smbconf" -nt "$profilesniplet" || silentexit "smb.conf is older than the AppArmor profile sniplet"
}

{
    echo "# autogenerated by $versionstring at samba start - do not edit!"
    echo ""
    testparm -s 2>/dev/null |sed -n '/^[ \t]*path[ \t]*=[ \t]*[^% \t]\{2,\}/ s�^[ \t]*path[ \t]*=[ \t]*\([^%]*\)$�"\1/"   rk,\n"\1/**" rwkl,�p'
} > "$tmp_profilesniplet"

diff "$profilesniplet" "$tmp_profilesniplet" >/dev/null && {
    rm -f "$tmp_profilesniplet"
    touch "$profilesniplet" # update timestamp - otherwise we'll have to check again on the next run
    silentexit "profile sniplet unchanged"
}

mv -f "$tmp_profilesniplet" "$profilesniplet"

grep -q '^/usr/sbin/smbd (\|^smbd (' /sys/kernel/security/apparmor/profiles || silentexit "smbd profile not loaded"

echo "Reloading updated AppArmor profile for Samba..."

# reload profile
"$aaparser" -r "$smbd_profile"
```

Also, I applied the following line in my Samba configuration which I thought might have provoked the problem, but it does not seems so:

```
include /etc/samba/includes.conf
```

My actual personall additions the config (shared folders) are all in the `include.conf`.

---

EDIT:

```
pi@RPi64:~ $ file /usr/share/samba/update-apparmor-samba-profile
/usr/share/samba/update-apparmor-samba-profile: Bourne-Again shell script, ISO-8859 text executable
```

Comment: what does `file /usr/share/samba/update-apparmor-samba-profile` tell us about the file getting the exec format error?

Comment: I added information to the question. Thanks for asking! Did you just mean a cat or something else?

Comment: no I mean for you to run the command `file /usr/share/samba/update-apparmor-samba-profile`

Comment: Oh, I updated the question with the output.